# Infinite loop for 4 images with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the next code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#imgone').hide().delay(500).fadeIn(1000).delay(4500).fadeOut(500);
    $('#imgtwo').hide().delay(1500).fadeIn(1000).delay(3500).fadeOut(500);
    $('#imgthree').hide().delay(2500).fadeIn(1000).delay(2500).fadeOut(500);
});
```

It's more a playground with jQuery. Well, first I wanted the first image to fade in, then the second one and then the final one. After this I wanted all the images to fade out after they have been loaded.

But I am thinking about two new issues:

1. create an infinite loop
2. use more than 3 images, but at once show only 3 (I realise this could affect the id's to be changed into something else)

Any ideas?

I will not post here how I tried to realise the loop, only one funny method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function runPics() {
    $('#imgone').hide().delay(500).fadeIn(1000).delay(4500).fadeOut(500);
    $('#imgtwo').hide().delay(1500).fadeIn(1000).delay(3500).fadeOut(500);
    $('#imgthree').hide().delay(2500).fadeIn(1000).delay(2500).fadeOut(500);
    } interval = setInterval(runPics, 3500);
});
```

This code sucks, right? :P

Comment: This is both awesome and terrifying.

Comment: t: Use callbacks? http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
$(function(){
    var images = ['#imgone', '#imgtwo', '#imgthree'],
         imgIx = 0;

    (function nextImage(){
        $(images[imgIx++] || images[imgIx = 0, imgIx++]).hide().delay(500).fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(500, nextImage);
    })();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwolves/UBpqT/)

---

or to show random images, 3 at a time:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="imgone"   style="display:none;">one</div>
    <div id="imgtwo"   style="display:none;">two</div>
    <div id="imgthree" style="display:none;">three</div>
    <div id="imgfour"  style="display:none;">four</div>
    <div id="imgfive"  style="display:none;">five</div>
    <div id="imgsix"   style="display:none;">six</div>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
    var images = ['#imgone', '#imgtwo', '#imgthree', '#imgfour', '#imgfive', '#imgsix'],
        parent = $('#parent');

    (function nextImage(){
        var imgs = images.slice();
        for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
            parent.append(
                $(imgs.splice(0|Math.random() * imgs.length, 1)[0]).hide().delay(1000*i+500).fadeIn(1000).delay(4500-(1000*i)).fadeOut(500, i ? $.noop : nextImage)
            );
        }
    })();
});
</script>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwolves/UBpqT/1/)

Comment: maybe I'm missing exactly what you're trying to do then :)  What do you mean not in the required order?

Comment: first it appears image #3, then #2, then #1, then #1 fades out, then #2 fades out and so on. I need to fade in #1, then #2, then #3. After this all of them to fade out in the same time and start again the cycle :)

Comment: it should be appearing in numerical order, it is in the jsfiddle I posted.  Didn't see that 2nd requirement though, I'll update the example.

Comment: how is it buggy?  My fiddle works perfectly!  :)  Also, just updated with something closer to what I think you want (although I made it randomize).  To make it not randomize, just delete the `|Math.random() * imgs.length`

Comment: it is buggy: http://inturnets.com/stacks/jQuery-loop/test.html maybe on fiddle it's a different environment or something.

Comment: no, you're missing the `parent` div that I created (for the purposes of re-ordering images), also I have them all hidden to start which is necessary :)

Comment: LOL. Awesome. Thanks! I suppose if I would like to drop the id's from the DIV's then I should change the second line which begins with var... Accepted.

Comment: you could actually change the `var` line to `var images = $('#parent div').get()` and everything else should work fine.

Comment: Cool. I modified a little bit, simplified actually. http://inturnets.com/stacks/jQuery-loop/test.html will have a parent div, inside some images without any other div and inline rules for the images. `var images = $('img').get();` Thanks a lot!

Comment: yep.  Getting a 404 (missing file) on jQuery on your test page

Answer (score 6):

I would do something like this:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    var $imgs = $('#slideshow > img'), current = 0;

    var nextImage = function() {
        if (current >= $imgs.length) current = 0;
        $imgs.eq(current++).fadeIn(function() {
            $(this).delay(3000).fadeOut(nextImage);
        })
    };
    nextImage();
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/JbrXd/4/

Comment: thanks but in your code only 1 image appears at once. I need to fade in #imgone, then #imgtwo, then #imgthree. After this all of them to fade out in the same time and start again the cycle :) And if possible to "read/use" more images, but always show only 3 of them in a group.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function runPics(){
        $('#imgone').delay(500).fadeIn(1000,function(){
            $('#imgtwo').fadeIn(1000,function(){
                $('#imgthree').fadeIn(1000,function(){
                    $('#imgone').fadeOut(500,function(){
                        $('#imgtwo').fadeOut(500,function(){
                            $('#imgthree').fadeOut(500,function(){
                                runPics();
                            })
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    };
    runPics();
});
```

I would do it like this. I think it makes more logical sense to complete each part, then after it is done move onto the next bit rather than setting a load of timers from the beginning.

The loop just runs the function from within itself after all the other things have finished.

This code is untested.

Edit: In response to comment, I updated the code...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function runPics(){
        $('#imgone').delay(500).fadeIn(1000,function(){
            $('#imgtwo').fadeIn(1000,function(){
                $('#imgthree').fadeIn(1000,function(){
                    $('#imgone').fadeOut(500)
                    $('#imgtwo').fadeOut(500)
                    $('#imgthree').fadeOut(500,function(){
                        $('#imgone').attr({src:'alreadyCachedImage.jpg'})
                        runPics();
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    };
    runPics();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, but it does not meet my requirements. I need to fade in #imgone, then #imgtwo, then #imgthree. After this all of them to fade out in the same time and start again the cycle :) And if possible to "read/use" more images, but always show only 3 of them in a group.

Comment: Thanks for your response code. However I accepted @cwolves's code, because that one covered also my question #2. Have a nice day! :)

Comment: I tried to address question 2 in the code a bit with the line: `$('#imgone').attr({src:'alreadyCachedImage.jpg'})` but maybe could be explained more. Also, someone voted me down on this question - I would like to kow why. Is there something wrong with my method?